# Writing a MATLAB .m File to Generate a Plot of Absolute Error as a Function of h (step-size)

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

This is the question I am to solve:

> Given the function $f(x)=\ln(3x+1)$, compute approximations to $f'(0)$ using the centered 3-point formula:
>
> $f'(x_0)\approx\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0-h)}{2h}$.
>
> Use Matlab to generate a plot of the absolute error as a function of the step-size h
> for the centered 3-point formula approximation to f′(0). At what values of h is the error
> minimized, that is, what step-sizes yield the maximum accuracy for this problem? (The magnitude of this number will be quite small.)

I have written the following MATLAB .m script file to generate the matrix of values $x, f(x), f'(x),$ and $\approx f'(x)$.  However, I cannot figure out how to evaluate the error at more than one value for $h$ at a time, if there is a way.

> h = 0.1;
>
> x = -0.3:h:0.3;
>
> f = @(x)(log(3.*x+1));
>
> fp = @(x)((3)./(3.*x+1));
>
> N = length(x);
>
> A = zeros(N,4);
>
> for i=1:N
>
> for j = 1:3
>
> ```
>    A(i,1) = x(i);
>
>    A(i,2) = f(A(i,1));
>
>    A(i,3) = fp(A(i,1));
> ```
>
> end%j
>
> end%i
>
> for i=2:N-1
>
> for j = 4
>
> ```
>    A(i,j) = (A(i+1,j-2)-A(i-1,j-2))./(2.*h);
> ```
>
> end%j
>
> end%i
>
> mdpt = ceil(N/2);
>
> pt = A(mdpt,4);
>
> err = abs(pt-fp(0));
>
> scatter(h,err)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably a few ways to answer this question. Perhaps you could generate the approximations of $f'(0)$ using the following code:

> x0 = 0;
>
> n = 1000;
>
> h = logspace(-16, -1, n); % Generates n numbers logarithmically spaced between 10^(-16) and 10^(-1)
>
> fp_approx = (f(x0 + h) - f(x0 - h)) ./ (2*h); % The approximations of f'(x_0)

Then compute the error as

> fp_exact = fp(x0)*ones(size(fp_approx));
>
> err = abs(fp_approx - fp_exact);

You could take $n$ much larger (say, $n = 10^6$), then find the minimum $h$ using `min`:

> [min_err, idx] = min(err);
>
> h(idx)

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I took away my for loops and basically pasted what you had suggested into my script file, so I have my assigned functions followed by the pasted material.  To complete the question, would adding the line "plot(err,h)" be correct?  If so, the plot generated is http://i43.tinypic.com/1628tb6.png  Which shows both a blue line at the bottom and one going toward the top middle.

Comment: Glad to help. I get that plot as well when I type `plot(err, h)`. Since you are interested in the absolute error as a function of h, you might want to swap the order of *h* and *err*: `plot(h, err)`. One caveat though -- because of the *very* small numbers involved (recall that some of the numbers are on the order of $10^{-16}$), the plot doesn't show the graph of the absolute error very clearly. Instead you could use a log-log plot, `loglog(h, err)`, which shows the absolute error as a function of $h$ much more clearly (on a log-log scale).